# petits veinards - figurative translation

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Ils ont permis à des petits veinards de devenir millionnaires du jour
>   au lendemain.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=Ils%20ont%20permis%20%C3%A0%20des%20petits%20veinards%20de%20devenir%20millionnaires%20du%20jour%20au%20lendemain.) gives: *They made little guys become millionaires overnight.*

[Linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/petits+veinards.html) translates *veinard* as *blighter* or *lucky devil*, so I assume it's a form of French vernacular or colloquialism.

What's the English equivalent of **petit veinard**? Same thing, or different meaning?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks a translation to English.

Comment: What is this forum for if not to clarify French expressions??

Comment: This is not a forum. It's OK to translate from English to French but not for French to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. *Veinard* is a colloquial word (but not vulgar). It means "someone who is very lucky".

According to the [Larousse definition](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/veinard/81282):

> Veinard : Qui a beaucoup de chance.

Using the word "petit" before it gives it a petty meaning, as if the person writing the sentence was expressing a form of jealousy towards these newly rich people.

**Origin of the expression**

This adjective is taken from *Avoir de la veine*. The origin of this expression is [not officially determined](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-a/2600-avoir-de-la-veine.html). However, the most popular (and logical) explanation is that it would come from the age of gold diggers.

Indeed, a *veine* expresses [a part of a mine where the mineral is located](https://www.littre.org/definition/veine).

> À force de creuser, il est tombé sur une veine d'or.

Since finding gold is a lucky thing, it possibly derived to the expression we know today.